# J4 -Custom Component - Router Unknown $pk in model

Tags: joomla-4.x, model, router

I've added Router Features today to my Custom Component - all works finde beside the fact that the $pk variable inside the model holds a curios value (202n) where 'n' is different for each element...

**Router:**

```
public function __construct(SiteApplication $app, AbstractMenu $menu, CategoryFactoryInterface $categoryFactory, DatabaseInterface $db)
    {
        $this->categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
        $this->db              = $db;

        $params = ComponentHelper::getParams('com_marathonmanager');
        $this->noIDs = (bool) $params->get('sef_ids');
        $categories = new RouterViewConfiguration('categories');
        $categories->setKey('id');
        $this->registerView($categories);
        $category = new RouterViewConfiguration('category');
        $category->setKey('id')->setParent($categories, 'catid')->setNestable();
        $this->registerView($category);

        $events = new RouterViewConfiguration('events');
        $events->setKey('id');
        $this->registerView($events);

        $event = new RouterViewConfiguration('event');
        $event->setKey('id');
        $this->registerView($event);

//        $this->registerView(new RouterViewConfiguration('featured'));
        $form = new RouterViewConfiguration('form');
        $form->setKey('id');
        $this->registerView($form);

        parent::__construct($app, $menu);

        $this->attachRule(new MenuRules($this));
        $this->attachRule(new StandardRules($this));
        $this->attachRule(new NomenuRules($this));
    }
```

**EventsNomenuRules:**

```
     *
     * @var RouterView
     * @since 3.4
     */
    protected $router;

    /**
     * Class constructor.
     *
     * @param   RouterView  $router  Router this rule belongs to
     *
     * @since   3.4
     */
    public function __construct(RouterView $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    /**
     * Dummymethod to fullfill the interface requirements
     *
     * @param   array  &$query  The query array to process
     *
     * @return  void
     *
     * @since   3.4
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function preprocess(&$query)
    {
        $test = 'Test';
    }

    /**
     * Parse a menu-less URL
     *
     * @param   array  &$segments  The URL segments to parse
     * @param   array  &$vars      The vars that result from the segments
     *
     * @return  void
     *
     * @since   3.4
     */
    public function parse(&$segments, &$vars)
    {
        // with this url: http://localhost/events/event-n/event-title.html
        // segments: [[0] => event-n, [1] => event-title]
        // vars: [[option] => com_marathonmanager, [view] => events, [id] => 0]

        $vars['view'] = 'event';
        $vars['id'] = substr($segments[0], strpos($segments[0], '-') + 1);
        array_shift($segments);
        array_shift($segments);
        return;
    }

    /**
     * Build a menu-less URL
     *
     * @param   array  &$query     The vars that should be converted
     * @param   array  &$segments  The URL segments to create
     *
     * @return  void
     *
     * @since   3.4
     */
    public function build(&$query, &$segments)
    {
        // content of $query ($segments is empty or [[0] => mywalk-3])
        // when called by the menu: [[option] => com_mywalks, [Itemid] => 126]
        // when called by the component: [[option] => com_mywalks, [view] => mywalk, [id] => 1, [Itemid] => 126]
        // when called from a module: [[option] => com_mywalks, [view] => mywalks, [format] => html, [Itemid] => 126]
        // when called from breadcrumbs: [[option] => com_mywalks, [view] => mywalks, [Itemid] => 126]

        // the url should look like this: /site-root/mywalks/walk-n/walk-title.html



        // if the view is not mywalk - the single walk view
        if (!isset($query['view']) || (isset($query['view']) && $query['view'] !== 'event') || isset($query['format']))
        {
            return;
        }
        $alias = $this->getAliasForEvent($query['id']);
        error_log('alias: ' . var_export($alias, true));
        if($alias){

            $segments[] = $alias;
        }else {
            $segments[] = $query['view'] . '-' . $query['id'];
        }
        // the last part of the url may be missing
        if (isset($query['slug'])) {
            $segments[] = $query['slug'];
            unset($query['slug']);
        }
        unset($query['view']);
        unset($query['id']);
    }

    private function getAliasForEvent($id){
        if(!is_numeric($id)){
            return false;
        }
        $app = Factory::getApplication();
        $db = Factory::getContainer()->get(DatabaseInterface::class);
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        try
        {
            $query->select($db->quoteName('alias'))
                ->from($db->quoteName('#__com_marathonmanager_events'))
                ->where($db->quoteName('id') . ' = :id')
                ->bind(':id', $id, ParameterType::INTEGER);
            $db->setQuery($query);
            $app->enqueueMessage('NICE', 'default');
            return $db->loadResult();
        }
        catch (RuntimeException $e)
        {
            $app->enqueueMessage($e->getMessage(), 'error');
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

In Fact when turning off SEF the event item url looks so:
https://joomla4.local:8890/index.php?option=com_marathonmanager&view=event&id=5&Itemid=1282
And if turned on:
https://joomla4.local:8890/marathon-manager-items/simm-2020-st-antoenien

**But in the Model:**

```
...
public function getItem($pk = null): object|bool
    {
        $app = Factory::getApplication();
        $pk = $app->input->getInt('id');

        error_log('EventModel::getItem() called with id: ' . $pk);

        if($this->_item === null)
        {
            $this->_item = array();
        }

        if(!isset($this->_item[$pk]))
        {
...
```

When checking the $pk var in the model it brings up a 202x number -which i cannot identify because its NOT the item ID

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I've got it now. I had to add a method to get the item ID based on the ALIAS of the item as visible below. Is this the correct way to handle this?

So in my **EventsNomenuRules**:

```
...
public function parse(&$segments, &$vars)
    {
        $vars['view'] = 'event';
        $vars['id'] = $this->getItemIdForAlias($segments[0]);
        array_shift($segments);
        array_shift($segments);
        return;
    }
...

private function getItemIdForAlias($alias){
        if(empty($alias)){
            return false;
        }
        $db = Factory::getContainer()->get(DatabaseInterface::class);
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        try
        {
            $query->select($db->quoteName('id'))
                ->from($db->quoteName('#__com_marathonmanager_events'))
                ->where($db->quoteName('alias') . ' = :alias')
                ->bind(':alias', $alias, ParameterType::STRING);
            $db->setQuery($query);
            return $db->loadResult();
        }
        catch (RuntimeException $e)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```